# Setting up SVN with repository on a home network NAS

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I was wondering if it is possible to setup SVN and Tortois etc with repositories residing on a home networked NAS such as a DS118 or similar ? I would like these repositories to be accessible to both a Windows machine and a Linux machine (if this may be required in the future), all connected to the same NAS.
cheers, GD

I have tried looking at the SVN subversion site for this dual boot case use.

Comment: Just install VisualSVN Server on any available Windows computer and make it available to other computers over your LAN. NAS itself isn't a requirement and isn't generally recommended since network storage adds performance penalty (negatively impacts performance of file operations in general).

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a Subversion *client* anyway. So you don't need to set it up on the server.